# Unable to raise Exception while mocking a whole python class in unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

Here is the original class:

```
class Original(object):
    def __ init__(self, path):
        self.xml = None
        self.path = path
        self.convert() # <----- I can't modify anything in my class

    def convert(self):
        #some code here
        self.xml = external_api_call # <------------this generates objects for this property
        self.transform()

    def transform(self):
        #some code
        if not self._xml:
            raise Exception('None value')
        for project in self.xml.projects:
            try:
                value = getattr(project, "name")
            except AttributeError:
                raise Exception('AttributeError')
            print('Yes it worked')
```

I want to have 100% coverage therefore, i tried to generate mock objects for external api calls. Unfortunately while using a mock object it never raises any exception.

```
with mock.patch('something.Original', autospec=True) as mock_object:
    mock_object.xml = None
    mock_object.transform()
```

It should generate an exception but it doesn't. I have also tried different approaches e.g side_effect property of mock object.

```
mock_object._xml.return_value
```

Comment: Instead of patching `Original`, patch only *external_api_call* like
`with mock.patch("something.external_api_call", lamda *args, **kws: None):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@patch('something.Original')
def test_case_1(Original):
    Original.xml.side_effect = Exception()
    Original.transform()
```